# Probabilistic properties that are invariant under a change of sample space.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This may be a standard question, but I couldn't find it anywhere. I am having trouble understanding why in many results in probability we can omit the actual structure $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, \mathbb{P})$ of a probability space; for instance, when we have a sequence of i.i.d  Bernoulli random variables $X_n$, is the fact that the $X_n$ converge almost surely independent of the choice of the probability space? In the sense that the $X_n$ can be defined in many probability spaces while still being Bernoulli. What about for r.v variables with other distributions? Is there a general criterion that allows this "probabilistic" way of thinking?

Any resource that is related to this would also be very helpful.

Comment: Note that a sequence of $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables converges almost surely iff it is eventually constant, with probability one.

Comment: @Math1000 By Bernoulli I don't mean that the image of the random variable is $\{0,1\}$, but that $P(X=0)=1/2$ and $P(X=1)=1/2$, so for instance they can take the value $2$ in a set of probably $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Terry Tao discusses exactly this matter here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/

Comment: Hi camilo. Would you be willing to outline the discussion here, for stackexchange?